# Meta data hierarchy in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, seo

Can anyone explain the meta hierarchy in Joomla, please? I see the global meta, but also at the article detail, category and menu level. I assume that the global is intended to serve as the crawled meta data in the event that the other don't exist, however I'm unclear on which takes priority, the menu level or article level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Joomla meta hierarchy is:

- Article - Highest priority
- Category
- Menu
- Global - Lowest priority

For example, if no meta is specified at the article level, then the category level is used, if no meta is specified at the category level then the menu level is used and so on.

For single articles, I tend to specify meta data at the menu level because I can also specify page headings and page titles at the same time.

For articles in a category blog, it's better to specify meta at the article level because category blog articles don't all have a unique menu item.