# How to change Website Information link shared on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, metadata

When I share my main website on Facebook, it's not showing the right information on Photo, website's name and website's description.

Is there any way I can customize this information? not just for me, but for all users who will share the website.

Link share (copy + paste). No buttons.

Comment: These Q/A might also be helpful: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5467/facebook-share-remove-the-joomla-content-management-system-lets-you-create - http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10001/how-to-change-or-hide-the-author-meta-tag-facebook-still-shows-the-author-meta/10003#10003

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To manage how your pages are shared on **Facebook** by users, Facebook has created [Open Graph Tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article) (e.g. article).

For example, you have to add in your site these tags in the head:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:description" content="....">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="...">
<meta property="og:image" content="...">
<meta property="og:url" content="...">
```

In this way, Facebook loads this information to create a Post or Like.

You can find several extension in JED's [Social Share](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/social-web/social-share) category, that can provide a straightforward method to generate the Open Graph Tags for your site.

Similarly, **Twitter** has also created [TwitterCards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image) tags (e.g. summary-large-image)to support the very same functionality (and there are extensions already supporting TwitterCards).

```
<meta property="twitter:title" content="...">
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:image:src" content="..">
<meta property="twitter:creator" content="@...">
```

Comment: Thank you. All changed, but not quite as desired. I've added a new photo, using open graph protocol, but instead of replacing the previous photos, it just added the new one to the preview options. I would like to remove the previous photos, and just keep the photo I've added with meta property, do you know how to do that? I'm using T3 Framework, plugins don't seem compatible, it did not changed anything.

Comment: Once Facebook loads information, it does not easily change it. A user can also manually customize the shared information. Facebook crawler, cache and cdn do not inmediately refresh the information. You can inspect how the crawler loads the page with Facebook's debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: to refresh a post posted on a fb page: click on the date of the post (it will open the post on a new tab). Click on the arrow, select "more option", then "refresh share attachment" (sometime you have to do it twice to get the picture)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the way that FB handles it, they effectively 'cache' whatever they find on a page each time they visit it, so if you change the image on a page they 'remember' both images.

But if you want them to 'forget' the original image, the best solution is to delete the posts in which it appears, then change the URL of the article in question, even just slightly, and repost the new URL to FB. At that point it treats it as an entirely new post and will only see the new image.

Comment: Images are on a responsive slideshow in main page (behind nav menu), I can't delete them.

Comment: You can clear the cache using the the Open Graph Debugger Tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/